# How can I get rid of the comment from geom_smooth in Rmd?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

When using `ggplot2`'s `geom_smooth` in R Markdown I get the comment

```
## `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

even if I include `echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, messages = FALSE` in the code cunks header:

[image: Comment and ggplot]

How can I get rid of that?

Example:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Title

```{r cars, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, messages = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm)
```
````

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code, you used `messages = FALSE` (plural), but it should be `message = FALSE` instead.